# How to get higher date form two dates

Tags: flutter

> there are two dates in this format

1. 22-10-2019 & 25-10-2019 (dd-MM-yyyy)

> how to get a higher date form this two

Comment: read `DateTime` / `DateFormat` class official docs

Comment: Maybe you can use isBefore? https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/isBefore.html

Comment: thanks, I will try

Comment: isBefore is worked on String. I want a method which works on var

Answer (score 0):

use [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl#-readme-tab-) package

```
    var df1 = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').parse('22-10-2019');
    var df2 = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').parse('25-10-2019');
    print(df1.isBefore(df2).toString());
```

Output: true